# Multiplying each adjacent element of 2 lists, the user inputs 1 list of the lists

Tags: list, multiplication

I found some code that works when I enter the lists manually. But when I enter a list through the console, it doesn't work quite like i'd like it to work.

```
# Initializing two lists
test_list1 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
test_list2=[]

for i in range(len(test_list1)):
    x=input("Unesite broj")
    test_list2.append(x)

print(test_list2)
y= len(test_list2)
print(y)

# Using map and lambda function to multiply two lists element-wise
res_list = list(map(lambda x, y: x * y, test_list1, test_list2))

# Printing the resultant list
print("Resultant list is : " + str(res_list))
```

I found the correct syntax for my problem, but user input is just not working for me.

The code works as intended when I enter values directly into the code:
# Initializing two lists
test_list1 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
test_list2 = [4, 5, 6, 2, 10]

```
# Using map and lambda function to multiply two lists element-wise
res_list = list(map(lambda x, y: x * y, test_list1, test_list2))

# Printing the resultant list
print("Resultant list is : " + str(res_list))
```

Comment: Maybe change this line - ```x=int(nput("Unesite broj"))```  as you need integer.

Answer (score 0):

['1', '2', '3', '45', '3']
5
Resultant list is : ['1', '222', '3333', '454545454545', '33333333']

is the result to the code, which is obviously false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).